# Get the Value from IntEdit to Init Dynamics ax

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

How can I get the value from `IntEdit` to a `Init` on the `datasource` of a table, the `IntEdit` have `Autodeclaration = yes`, this is my code:

```
Int Var; 
Var = IntEditField.value(); //Doesn't work
Var = str2int(IntEditField.valueStr()); //Doesn't work
print Var;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to assign the value of `IntEditField` when the form opens? `IntEditField.value()` should work. The table datasource on a form is initialized when the form is initialized. You can assign by doing `IntEditField.value(5);`

Comment: Hi @AlexKwitny, Thank you for answer.. I need to get the value of a IntEditField on a Init of a Table

Comment: You need to provide more code. When does the table init occur in your scenario? If it's a form object, you need to pass it to the table's init method generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FormIntControl.value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa855681.aspx) *do* return the int value of the control, so

```
Int var = IntEditField.value();
```

should work. It will return zero of cause if the control has not been set. Beware, on `FormRealControl` it is named `realValue`, on FormStringControl `text`, consistency sucks.

In older versions than AX 2012, you should place a semicolon after declarations like this:

```
Int var; 
;
var = IntEditField.value();
```

Also, after setting the `AutoDeclaration` property, always recompile the form otherwise run-time errors or wrong behavior occurs.

This and other similar questions indicates you are not accustomed to using [bound controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa855681.aspx) or [edit methods](http://aslam111.blogspot.dk/2014/01/display-edit-methods-in-ax-2012.html).